# Catching DSum Null Results in Incorrect Calculation

Tags: ms-access, vba

`j` and `d` both evalulate the same function however when I use `If IsNull` to catch any Null Values the value of d is not correctly evaluated. What is causing this?

```
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    j = DSum("Count", "qry_nihr_unique")
    If IsNull(d = DSum("Count", "qry_nihr_unique")) Then
        MsgBox "No records were found for the data criteria you entered"
        GoTo ESub
    Else
        Me.un_p.Value = d
    End If

    Debug.Print "j = " & j
    Debug.Print "d = " & d


    j = 58
    d = 0
```

**Updated Code After Answer**

```
    Dim d
    d = DSum("Count", "qry_nihr_unique")
    If IsNull(d) Then
        MsgBox "No records were found for the data criteria you entered"
        GoTo ESub
    Else
        Me.un_p.Value = d
    End If
```

After HansUp's answer below I believe this is the most efficient way to write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `IsNull()`, the code checks whether `d` is equal to the `DSum()` expression.  It's an equality test, and nothing is assigned to `d`.  So the value of `d` remains unchanged --- it was initialized as zero and remains zero.

The situation is much like this Immediate window session:

```
? DSum("id", "tblFoo")
 134 
d = 0
? (d = DSum("id", "tblFoo"))
False
? d
 0
? IsNull(d = DSum("id", "tblFoo"))
False
? d
 0
```

The following statement will assign the `DSum()` result to `d`; not test whether the two are equal:

```
d = DSum("id", "tblFoo")
? d
 134
```

Comment: So in my code I have to test the `IsNull` then duplicate the line to assign the value to d? Edit: I've updated my code to reflect this, is this the most concise method?

Comment: My best guess is declare `d` as Variant.  Assign the `DSum()` result to `d`.  Then check `IsNull(d)`.